# RcppEigen as an argument fails

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

I am trying to create a function that calls (and outputs) an Eigen matrix with long doubles, using RcppEigen.

When I compile with:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::Matrix<long double, 4, 4> A_matrix_LPPLS_RcppEigen(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>>& onesfgh_LPPLS) {
}
```

it works (of course, there is a warning that the function does nothing). But when I do the same with:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::Matrix<long double, 4, 4> A_matrix_LPPLS_RcppEigen(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 4>>& onesfgh_LPPLS) {
}
```

it fails.

It also fails if I try with long double in the argument (with the combination that previously worked, when using a double):

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::Matrix<long double, 4, 4> A_matrix_LPPLS_RcppEigen(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<long double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>>& onesfgh_LPPLS) {
}
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: "but you can't export a function returning a Matrix<long double>" quoting Stéphane Laurent in a comment yesterday on one of your other questions. There simply is no support in R for `long double`. As it stands you have to convert to `double` for both input and output.

Comment: Yes, exporting a function returning a Matrix<long double> works. In fact, I wanted to ask about this a bit later. And the last 3 digits (out of 17) shown in R, are different for a long double and a double (admittedly, the double is not through Eigen, but through Armadillo). I guess Rcpp is casting automatically the long double into double.

Comment: @AnarcocapitalistaSocialdemocr R has a single floating point type with 64 bits, and a single integer type with 32 bits.  That is all well documented. You have a series of question here that all leave the impression you assume you work with other type _in R_ or on the interface.  You can't.  You can take advantage of them _outside of R_ but the results you report back have to be mapped to `double` and `int`.

Comment: Results (after shortening the result): `> sprintf("%.17f",tail(onesfgh_LPPLS_arma))
"-1.32766226314271640"
> sprintf("%.17f",tail(onesfgh_LPPLS_eigen))
"-1.32766226314271663"

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You are completely right. Sorry if I was not precise enough. I understand that R has a single floating type. I can try to do calculations with long double or boost multiprecision in C++ if I am able to, but everything should go back to double for R. Just one point: I am able to return a long double with Eigen without casting into double. I guess Rcpp does this automatically for me.

Comment: Yes, sorry,  we have a `long double` to `double` cast but it will of course be lossy.  You only get the `double` precision and range at the interface.

Comment: I do not completely understand what "lossy" means: do you mean that the extra precision of a long double (with respect to a double) will be lost, since R only accepts "doubles"? (this would be fine for me); or do you mean that the Rcpp cast of long double into double has some additional loss of precision, with respect to what it would be to cast from a long double into a double in C++, and then pass a standard double from C++ into R? In other words: can I use the (implicit) cast existing so far, or am I better off casting explicitly in C++?

Comment: You cannot represent 128 bit content in 64 bits. Hence "lossy".  That is a general computer science topic you can read up on, and is not specific to R.  I just need to remind you that the interface from and to R only has `double` at 64 bits.  Approximately 16 digits of precision.

Comment: Understood, thank you. So, now knowing that one can return a long double into R, may I reask again the original question that opened this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second variant does not work, since RcppEigen supports only dynamic matrices and vectors for automatic conversion from an R object to an Eigen object. This makes perfect sense, since R objects are inherently dynamic in size. Hence the dimension arguments in Eigen *must* be either 1 or `Dynamic` when conversion from R is needed.

The third form fails because you are trying to initialize an Eigen object using `long double` based on an R object using `double`. Remember that with `Eigen::Map`, the R and the Eigen object share the same memory. That cannot work if the data types are different and you have to do a conversion somewhere. If I remove the `Eigen::Map`, i.e. use

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::Matrix<long double, 4, 4> A_matrix_LPPLS_RcppEigen(Eigen::Matrix<long double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& onesfgh_LPPLS) {
}
```

it does compile. I have not tried if it works correctly.

Comment: Good explanation, @RalfStubner, thank you very much. Now I understand.